# Binding a DataPager to ComboBox?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, datapager, elementname

I have a comboxbox defined like this (basically):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="pageViewSize">
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">5</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>10</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>20</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>30</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>50</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>100</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

Now i would like my DataPager's PageSize (which is the source to a DataGrid) be bound to this ComboBox's SelectedItem.Value (or is it SelectedValue?):

```
<DataPager PageSize="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Value, ElementName=pageViewSize}" Source="{Binding PageView}"/>
```

This, unfortunately, is not working. The initial pagesize is not 10. And whenever i changed the selection in the ComboBox nothing happens to the displayed pagesize in the DataGrid.

**What am i doing wrong?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From DataPager.PageSize documentation:

> The source typically implements the IPagedCollectionView interface. In this case, PageSize gets or sets the IPagedCollectionView.PageSize of the IPagedCollectionView.
>
> If the source is a collection that implements IEnumerablebut not IPagedCollectionView, the DataPager ignores PageSize.

Maybe your data source doesn't properly support PageSize?

---

**EDIT:** <strike>I currently have the same issue as you</strike> I had the same issue as you, it was fixed by using @devdigital's answer.

I'm using data binding instead of element binding, on radio buttons + custom converter instead of combo, but it applies in the same way.

What I'm doing is data binding `IsChecked` to a value in my View Model, with a custom two-way converter checking whether value is equal to converter's parameter.

So here is an example from one of my RadioButtons:

```
IsChecked="{Binding MyBindedValue, Converter={StaticResource EqualStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=5, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

And your `DataPager`, modified:

```
<DataPager PageSize="{Binding MyBindedValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Source="{Binding PageView}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `Mode` to `TwoWay`.

```
PageSize="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Value, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=pageViewSize}"
```

Comment: i updatred the original post. for some reason the combobox snippet was not appearing in the final post. weird.